# cut operation - weird behavior

Tags: linux, shell, unix

cut operation is giving unexpected results due to "*" in the input data , how to fix it..

the following will explain better :

```
$ line="000067     (base 16)         SOFT * RITE, INC."
$ vendoroui=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1`
$ echo $vendoroui
000067
$ vname=`echo $line | cut -d' ' -f4-$NF`
$ echo $vname
1 bb bn btest.txt btmp.txt cc cut if sedTbKkAE sorted start.txt t10.sh t11.sh t12.sh t13.sh t14.sh t1.sh t2.txt t3.sh t4.sh t5.sh t6.sh t7.sh t8.sh t9.sh tmp RITE, INC.
```

this is due to the '*' in the inPut, how to fix it??

Comment: Where does `$NF` come from? If you want field 4 to the end, use `cut -f 4-`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote your `line` variable...

```
vname=`echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f4-$NF`
```

Also, when you use $vname be sure to quote it too...

```
echo "$vname"
```

Comment: +1 for the advice to quote. But no, the *assignment* to `line` would not have expanded the asterisk because it was in quotes. The unquoted variable in `echo $line` expanded the variable into words and performed globbing.

Comment: @glenn: you are totally right; the expansion would happen on echo. So when he was echoing $vname it was doing the expansion there. You can either escape the * or quote everywhere (which is the right thing to do); updated to reflect this advice.